# Redirect a request for a file to the file in a sub-directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have searched for days for an answer to this ModRewrite question and have tried numerous solutions without success. Can anyone help, please?

I have a site http://www.xxxx.co.uk
I would like someone to request a simple URL such as URL/mobile (with no file extension)
This would be redirected to a sub-folder called URL/mobile and access a file called http://www.xxxx.co.uk/mobile/mobile.php

Any help will be gratefully received.